# Error deploying CXF webservice on Tomee+

Tags: java, apache-tomee

We are getting the following error in deploying a cfx2.0 webservice on Tomee(1.6.0). Please help!

```
SEVERE: Error deploying CXF webservice for servlet com.vbvbv.TweetyWSImpl


java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast $Proxy52 to org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.wsdl.extensions.SoapBinding
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SOAPBindingUtil.getProxy(SOAPBindingUtil.java:104)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SOAPBindingUtil.getSoapBinding(SOAPBindingUtil.java:275)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SOAPBindingUtil.createSoapBinding(SOAPBindingUtil.java:418)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory.createSoapBinding(SoapBindingFactory.java:212)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory.createBindingInfo(SoapBindingFactory.java:197)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBaseBindingFactory.createBindingInfo(AbstractBaseBindingFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createBindingInfo
```

Comment: Is it working on any other servlet container? It looks like a code error...

Comment: Its working on Apache Axis

Comment: That is not a servlet cointainer, but another web services library. Could you share the `com.vbvbv.TweetyWSImpl`, the ws interface and the cxf.xml?